# Arraylist on parseserver is not being updated

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parse-server

I have an arraylist column on parse that i would like to update as shown within the following code. However, in the parse column it only shows "[]" after updating the column from clicking a selection of users within the listview. Thanks.

```
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alternative_follow);



        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isfollowing") == null){
            List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("isfollowing", emptyList);
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
        }


        listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterSelected = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, users);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterSelected);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                CheckedTextView textview = (CheckedTextView)view;

                //CHECK IF TEXTVIEW IS CHECKED

                if (textview.isChecked()){

                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isfollowing").add(users.get(position));
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
                }else{
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isfollowing").remove(users.get(position));
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
                }


            }
        });

        users.clear();
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public String done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    if (objects.size() > 0) {

                        for (ParseUser object : objects) {
                            users.add(object.getUsername());
                        }
                        arrayAdapterSelected.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the add function does not appear to be working with a lot of people including me ,so a solution for that problem is creating a List and then setting it to be equal to the current user list in the on create method and then updating that list and finally setting the current user list to the newly created and updated one , example :

```
private static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alternative_follow);

    array = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isfollowing");
    array.add("New Item 1");
    array.add("New Item 2"); 
    array.add("New Item 3");

    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("isfollowing" , array);
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
}
```

you should do all the work on the created ArrayList and once all the required changes has been made then update the user "isfollowing" list with the created array and save